# Serial port "read" operation is not working

Tags: linux, serial-port, linux-device-driver

I am trying to read data through serial port but the read operation is always returning 0.

```
// Opening COM port and m_fd returned a valid number
m_fd =  open (m_com_port, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC); 

//Read operation
length = read(m_fd, &ch, 1);  // length is always zero

setserial -g /tmp/xdl/serial/com_7 
# /tmp/xdl/serial/com_7, UART: undefined, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 45
```

Can some one point what mistake I am doing and why setserial command gives undefined

Comment: did you try to read your serial port with other programs? does it work?
Are you sure that there is traffic on that serial line?

Comment: I tried echo 'Hello' > /tmp/xdl/serial/com_7 and it works fine.

Comment: `echo 'Hello'> /tmp/xdl/serial/com_7`  is a write operation so you are not exaclty reproducing your problem with other programs. Try to `cat`, `hexdump`, `minicom` in order to *read* like your example

Answer (score 0):

Your BUFFER_SIZE may be too small and it has to provide a buffer of large enough.

The BUFFER_SIZE is the third parameter of read function.

Comment: I am trying to read one by one character
 unsigned int length;
 unsigned char ch; 
 
 length = read(m_fd, &ch, 1)

Comment: What is your  linux serial driver ?